# View PDF in Android's default PDF viewer

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, cordova

I'm working on an Android app using [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) (an API that takes a web app and compiles it as a native app on any phone platform).

As part of the app, users need to be able to view PDFs. It seems like the easiest way to handle this is to open each PDF url in the Android native browser, then let the browser handle it. This should open the Android device's default PDF viewer, whatever that is. However, the browser immediately errors out when given a PDF file to open. More specifically, the browser does not seem to appear, and an error is logged after some time.

I hijacked the javascript error reporting function to see what was going on when I tried to open a PDF in the browser:

```
onError = new function(err, url, line) {
    console.log("ConferenceApp: Error: "+err+", "+url+", "+line);
}
```

Unfortunately, this is what is printed to the console:

```
ConferenceApp: Error: undefined, undefined, undefined
```

...which isn't very informative.

Then I looked into opening the default PDF viewer directly. This would require opening a 3rd party app on the Android file system. I found a plugin called Webintent that would do this job on the Android, but from its [website](http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins/) and its [github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent/) I discovered that this was very out of date with Phonegap and I couldn't find any more recent versions.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: There is no "default PDF viewer" for the Android OS. Devices may or may not have one or more PDF viewers installed.

Comment: I know, but users can set their "default" viewer to something like Adobe Reader if they have it installed. So I"m looking for a way to access that.

Comment: "However, the browser immediately errors out when given a PDF file to open" -- could you be more specific? What is the nature of the "errors out"? How have you "given a PDF file", and to what?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going on when the browser errors out... mobile apps are not very talkative error-wise. In short, when I call window.open with a url like "www.google.com", a system browser opens within 10 seconds. When I call it with "http:// [path to any pdf file]", nothing happens and an error is logged. (See updated post)